Azure SQL backup is not available to restore to a new server
I am creating a simple DR plan for my Azure application.  The app's RTO is up to a week so it is not a critical app so I don't need to setup Active/Passive servers or any type of automated failover.
If the datacenter loses power for six hours, I don't care.  I'm really just solving DR for some event that takes the whole datacenter offline, such as fire, natural disaster, etc.
With that understanding, I was looking at how to restore an Azure SQL database to another location.

On the database Overview page, there is an option to "Restore".  The problem with that is there is no option to restore to another logical server.  Which I assume is required if the datacenter is unavailable.
I believe my best option is to create a new server and db, and use the backup to populate it.  I just have to update the connection string in my app, yes?

Therein lies my problem.  I'm creating a new database on a new server and on the "Additional Settings" step you can choose to Use Existing Data and select a backup.  I see backups, but not for the db I need.
I have two dbs on the server.  Db1 is in the backup list is a Standard tier, serverless with geo-redundant backup.  Db2 that is not in the backup list is a Basic tier, serverless, with zone-redundant backup.
I'm wondering if its either 1) the different tier or 2) the different backup schemes that is preventing me from using a db backup?  I tried changing the tier of Db2, to the standard-tier and changed to a geo-redundant backup but the db is still not visible.
Is the Db2 config really the issue and it just takes time (hours/days?) to establish the geo-redundant backups, or is there something else?
UPDATE
I think it took the geo-redundant time to kick in.  I checked again today and there is a backup to restore.

You can consider to configure backup redundancy of the Azure SQL automated backup then you will be able to perform what is called a geo-restore to another logical server on the same subscription.


Thanks Alberto, and I have geo-redundancy set.  The problem is the backups for a particular database are not showing up in the Create Database screen.  (the one in your screenshot).

Geo-restore only works for the same subscription. Is that your scenario?

It is the same subscription
